# Buscar un valor de una propiedad de objeto, este objeto esta en un arreglo javascript o en typescript angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

tengo un arreglo en una propiedad de angular:

```
this.user.notify
```

que trae:

```
[…]
​
0: {…}
​​
__v: 0
​​
_id: "5ff5ffd10646c02f640fae15"
​​
alert: true
​​
articleid: "5fea381dfcd74a185cca273c"
​​
articletitle: "libro prueba 1"
​​
date: "2021-01-06T18:22:09.665Z"
​​
message: " comentó el libro: "
​​
userid: "5fea3bb0fcd74a185cca2742"
​​
username: "usertest1"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
length: 1
​
```

y necesito comprobar si la propiedad **alert** de cada objeto del arreglo es *true*,
ya intenté con:

```
this.user.notify.includes({alert:true});//Deberia devolverme true que es lo que espero
```

también:

```
const notify = this.user.notify;
notify.includes({alert:true});devuelve valor true que es lo que espero
```

por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar o decirme que estoy haciendo mal o si no es con el método includes o como lo harían ustedes, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto de la siguiente manera

```js
const miArray = [{alert:true},{alert:false},{alert:true}];

miArray.forEach(el => {
  if (el["alert"] == true) {
    console.log(el, "es true");
  } else {
    console.log(el, "no es true");
  }
});
```

Usa `forEach` para recorrer cada elemento de un array

Para obtener una propiedad, puedes usar

```
obj.propiedad

// Tabnién aceptado
obj["propiedad"]
```

**Comprobando la existencia de un elemento dentro de un objeto**

Puedes usar `hasOwnProperty`, esto evaluará si el objeto posee o no una propiedad

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty("propiedad"))
    console.log("contiene la propiedad")
else
    console.log("no contiene la propiedad")
```

El método `hasOwnProperty` te retorna un true si el objeto tiene la propiedad y false si el objeto no la tiene

```js
const miArray = [{alert:true},{alert:false},{alert:true},{hello:"world"}];

miArray.forEach(el => {
  if (el.hasOwnProperty("alert")) {
    console.log(el, "tiene alert");
  } else {
    console.log(el, "no tiene alert");
  }
});
```

**Comprobando el tipo de un elemento**

Usa `typeof` para comprobar el tipo de un elemento

```js
console.log(typeof "hello world")
console.log(typeof 1)
console.log(typeof true)
console.log(typeof undefined)
console.log(typeof {})
console.log(typeof [])
console.log(typeof null)
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, lo acabo de implementar y funciona bien

Comment: @JohnyVillegas, si te sirvió, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que otros usuarios con un problema similar sepan que esto les puede ayudar.